# Difference between setParameter and set specific type parameters in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate's [Query](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html) class has setters for any type of primitive parameter such as `setString` `setBoolean` `setLong` etc, but it also has a `setParameter` method which receives an `Object` and can replace all other setters.

Since they are not deprecated, is there any advantage to using specific type parameters in terms of performance? 
Should `setParameter` be used only with custom Objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

based on cursory read of the implementation of the `Query` class in [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate/3.2.3.ga/org/hibernate/impl/AbstractQueryImpl.java#AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter%28int%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Corg.hibernate.type.Type%29).

> is there any advantage to using specific type parameters in terms of performance?

Yeah, as if you directly call the `setParameter` function, the hibernate will need to "guess" the type of the object. But, It looks like that those method (`setString`, `setBoolean`, etc) just a convenient method to set a parameter. Because, in the end, these function will call function `setParamater(int,Object,Type)`. Which is, the same with the `setParameter` function.

> Should `setParameter` be used only with custom Objects?

Not necessary. I mean, you still be able to use an `Integer` or the other wrapper class (`Boolean`, `Float`, etc). It just that, there is additional operation that hibernate needs to do to check what type the value is and handle it properly.